# Is it possible to map a field to a custom template radio button group?

Tags: django, django-formtools

Question in the title.

I have a form like so

```
class SelectTypeForm(forms.Form):

the_type = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I have a custom template with a radio button group.  How can make the field get the selected value?

Answer (score 0):

Go away from your `CharField`. Hopefully I understand you correctly and you want to have a radio-button-group with multiple options. Each option represents a string. If the user decides to click the second presented radio-button, the string `'is_stored'` gets stored.

```py
class SelectTypeForm(forms.Form):
    choose_type = forms.ChoiceField(label='your type field', choices=(
        ('type_a', 'This string'),
        ('type_b', 'is stored'),
        ('type_c', 'if selected')
    ), widget=forms.RadioSelect, initial='type_b')
```

If this is not what you meant, please provide your 'custom template with a radio button group'.